# Using a function from a built-in module in your own module - Python

Tags: python, function, math, module, jupyter-notebook

I'm new with Python and new on Stackoverflow, so please let me know if this question should be posted somewhere else or you need any other info :). But I hope someone can help me out with what seems to be a rather simple mistake...

I'm working with Python in Jupyter Notebook and am trying to create my own module with some selfmade functions/loops that I often use. However, when I try to some of the functions from my module, I get an error related to the import of the built-in module that is used in my own module.

The way I created my own module was by:

1. creating different blocks of code in a notebook and downloading it
   as  *'Functions.py'* file.
2. saving this *Functions.py* file in the folder that i'm currently working in (with another notebook file)
3. in my current notebook file (where i'm doing my analysis), I import my module with '*import Functions'*.

So far, the import of my own module seems to work. However, some of my self-made functions use functions from built-in modules. E.g. my *plot_lines()* function uses *math.ceil()* somewhere in the code. Therefore, I imported 'math' in my analysis notebook as well. But when I try to run the function plot_lines() in my notebook, I get the error *"NameError: name 'math' is not defined"*.

I tried to solve this error by adding the code 'import math' to the function in my module as well, but this did not resolve the issue.

**So my question is**: how can I use functions from built-in Python modules in my own modules?

Thanks so much in advance for any help!

Comment: `import math` in your `Functions.py`.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

I just added a new block of code to my own module which imports 'math'. 
I already tried something like that, but I guess I had to restart my kernell to reload my module. Otherwise, the updated module file was not actually reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone encounters the same issue:
add 'import math' to your own module.

Make sure that you actually reload your adjusted module, e.g. by restarting your kernell!